# Rails Select helper not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

None of the below select helpers are working only for the selected part:

```
<%= f.select(:project_name, @parent_projects.collect {|p| [ p.name, p.name ] }, {:include_blank => 'Select Project'}, {:selected => "#{Project.find_by_identifier(params[:parent_id]).name}"}) %>
```

OR

```
<%= f.select(:project_name, @parent_projects.collect {|p| [ p.name, p.name ] }, {:include_blank => 'Select Project'}, :selected => "#{Project.find_by_identifier(params[:parent_id]).name}") %>
```

I am getting no error message but the the select box is not pre-selecting the name.

Checked the API from [here](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/select#52-selected)

Comment: <%= value = "#{Project.find_by_identifier(params[:parent_id]).name}" %> is returning the name of the project as expected.

Comment: Even tried manually like this: <%= f.select(:project_name, @parent_projects.collect {|p| [ p.name, p.name ] }, {:include_blank => 'Select Project'}, {:selected => "project_name"}) %> still doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the official docs for [`select`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-select) -- that method has more magic that you need; it's more for constructing a select list for a particular model/attribute. Since you are constructing the parts manually, you should use the more direct [`select_tag`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-select_tag) method.

```
select_tag('project_name',
    options_from_collection_for_select(@parent_projects,
        'name', 'name',
        Project.find_by_identifier(params[:parent_id]).name),
    :include_blank => 'Select Project')
```

[options_from_collection_for_select](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/options_from_collection_for_select) makes your options list, and takes a parameter for which is selected.